# How to highlight vertical cursor position?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A previous editor I used (probably Atom) had a feature to highlight the current column of the cursor location. That combined with the default horizontal highlight meant that you always had a faint crosshair pointed at your cursor.

I'm struggling to find the same thing for VSCode. Everything I search for talks about either a static line at a particular column number, or multiple cursors for vertical selection, neither of which is what I'm looking for. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I searched for `CrossHair` in the Extensions view and found: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bitlang.vscode-crosshair

Comment: That might work @Mark thanks
Edit: appears to be very broken on my system

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with VSCode and didn't found good solution, so I created an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IuriiBarlukov.cursor-column-highlight&ssr=false#overview) for this.

Actually it just adds the vertical line with `editor.lineHighlightBackground` color. So it looks good by default. And you can customize appearance with this property or with special `cursorColumnColor` and `cursorColumnBorderColor` properties.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ydW.png)